# Split window buffers

Tags: window-splitting

Scenario: I'm working with a horizontal split

```
---------------------
|  File 1  |  File 2 |
|          |         |
|          |         |
----------------------
```

and I'm working on File 2.

Question 1: Sometimes when I use a command like `M-x helm-mini` and load up another file the new file opens up in File 1's window.  I'd like it to open up in the current window

This happens:

```
----------------------                   ----------------------
|  File 1  | *File 2* |                  | File 3  |  File 2  |
|----------|----------|   --Select--->   |         |          |
|       Helm          |                  |         |          |
----------------------                   |---------------------
```

I'd like to keep file 1 active.  This is very annoying Emacs behavior

Question 2: `M-x helm-mini` (for example) does a few other annoying thing.  First, it expands the size of File 2's window to full width.  Secondly, the temp vertically split buffer for the `helm-mini` buffer is full width as well

Preferably I'd like this to happen:

```
---------------------                   ----------------------
|  File 1  |  File 2 |                  | File 1  |  File 3  |
|          |---------|   --Select--->   |         |          |
|          | Helm    |                  |         |          |
----------------------                  |---------------------
```

I'd like the new split helm screen (or any new command window) to only fill the current working window.  Is that possible?

-- Update --

I didn't intend to make this a helm only type question.  I think simply put I'd like:  If I have 2 files horizontally split I don't want emacs to disturb those windows unless I open a new file.

Like if I'm working in file1, file2 window should *never* change.  I can't stand when emacs does this.  I am either working on file2 or using it as a reference -- I don't want that buffer changed

Comment: Interesting edit to this question.  Apparently what vim calls vertical splits are horizontal splits in emacs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 2, you want to set `helm-split-window-in-side-p` non-nil.

For question 1, your desired behavior is how it works on my setup, and I can't find anything in my `helm` config that seems to be affecting this.  I suspect `helm` is respecting the vanilla Emacs settings that affect whether buffers try to open in the active window.  I'm not very familiar with those, so maybe someone else can weigh in.

Comment: helm-split-window-in-side-p seems to be what I want.  I'll try this out for a while